# Simple Turtle graphics issue: reading lines from file, outputting to turtle screen. Last line of output is off

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am working on an assignment for school. It's simple, involving file io and turtle graphics, and I am having trouble figuring out why the last line appears disconnected from the rest like this: [picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaKHB.png)

```
import turtle
def gfxFileIO():
    t1 = turtle.Turtle()
    window = turtle.Screen()
    f=open("file.txt","r")
    count = 1
    t1.penup()
    t1.rt(270)
    t1.fd(250)
    t1.rt(270)
    t1.fd(300)
    t1.rt(270)
    t1.write("Your file: ", font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))
    t1.fd(45)
    for line in f:
        t1.write(str(count) + ". " + str(line), font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))
        t1.fd(16)
        count += 1
window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Does the third line of your file have an extra line break?

Comment: Doesn't seem to. I tested it with a different file (more lines) and it did the same thing

Comment: Wow that is the issue actually. I think the case I tested with had the same issue for some odd reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Text file had extra line breaks. Thank you user DYZ

Answer (score 0):

As posted, this code doesn't run.  `window` is a local variable of `gfxFileIO()` but is used globally.  The one function, `gfxFileIO()` is never called.  Now that the data input problem has been resolved, let's rethink the example code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT_SIZE = 16
FONT = ("Arial", FONT_SIZE, "normal")

def gfxFileIO(turtle, file_name):
    file = open(file_name)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.rt(270)
    turtle.fd(250)
    turtle.rt(270)
    turtle.fd(300)
    turtle.rt(270)
    turtle.write("Your file: ", font=FONT)
    turtle.fd(FONT_SIZE * 3)  # double space

    count = 1

    for line in file:
        turtle.write("{}. {}".format(count, line), font=FONT)
        turtle.fd(FONT_SIZE)
        count += 1

yertle = Turtle()

gfxFileIO(yertle, "file.txt")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```